# Mongodb update issue

Tags: mongodb

I have photos collection which have 5000 documents like this:

```
   {
    "id": 1.0,
    "albumId": 1.0,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "http://placehold.it/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/92c952"
   },
    ...
   {
    "_id": 5000.0,
    "albumId": 9.0,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "http://placehold.it/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/771796"
   }
```

I try to update url and thumbnailUrl fields on mongoshell as below code. Take a random value in pics array includes 100 values and then update for url and thumbnailUrl fields of each document in photos collection:

```
 var pics = [
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/IGmMRSuh6Qo',
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/t4mQXex4Peo',
     ...
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/bjDpgPvCcM0',
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/6cmZLC4Tq9s'          
    ];
    var rd = (cb)=>{
      return cb(pics[Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)]);
    }
    for(var i=1;i<=5000;i++){
    rd((res)=>{db.getCollection('photos').updateOne({"_id":i},{$set: 
      {"url":res,"thumbnailUrl":res}});})   
    }
```

Output: There are many documents have value of url and thumbnailURL fields are undefined.

[image]

Output required:
All of 5000 documents should be updated new value for url and thumbnailUrl fields. No document have undefined value in url and thumbnailUrl field.

If I take random value between 10 and 1, output is OK. But it not OK when I take between 100 and 1. I think this is asynchronous issue.

I made photos collection by this link:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

And then I make pics array like this:

```
[
'https://unsplash.com/photos/IGmMRSuh6Qo',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/t4mQXex4Peo',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/WF2lvywxdMM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/gnm2op0m2pw',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/woP_9Ps2RWY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/XSbJiHcPUAk',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/9KkpIPFWIeM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/XpqRnutVWCM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/u535hc1fR8w',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/e3Xfmhfbxj4',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/jNpttMRlb_Y',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/4TET084JWaA',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/EeN8KSwYMjw',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/sYIqGW3hufI',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/tgmGOhXVuoI',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/nYugmV-SY6s',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/f5Y_m2bD_Tw',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/MEZDyn98La8',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/peFXR4binOk',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/SurmPrJ4Rts',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/h-dR-XFJXis',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/-LTxAmtpI5g',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/7bVMdNYzH_8',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/h8wi7UONunE',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/DmUbkltYsKI',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/aEnH4hJ_Mrs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/FTW8ADj5igs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/S2YssLw97l4',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/P8M_y-uI3gs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/1rrCIeGUtcM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/RBouLnm0L0Q',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/soyhgESoGVc',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/PUVgHyBgZn8',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/CEa3F_sPvqg',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/fJzmPe-a0eU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/70RHiKO9kj8',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/n2WHxdFtIXU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/cqrEoS9hRBc',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/cwz9_Pqd8Zs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/BJAKGX0-9_s',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/hw_sKmjb0ns',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/Pn0XP2Klbcw',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/XsmfoZl6a8Q',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/6vwrVGrxOKE',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/8WODX7nO2JE',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/FWOGqSKq_Cs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/s_IYpaTaueQ',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/pTrHHGrxeOE',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/xI_-wFJhCiM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/JckbjvEWQts',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/hDkHSqzGFCA',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/wcNyOYH0_kY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/0Hf3SuP-Muc',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/8ziKncAPUpY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/iJY-h1wEMK4',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/FGESRgJ-Aog',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/LmFV2vafmS0',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/GSf90gw9YHw',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/bjDpgPvCcM0',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/6cmZLC4Tq9s',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/WCz-Kp72lpU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/N7WPtFds0nU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/qF1oacfAqnI',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/29skLU6lfjo',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/Ixzs6GZwdtY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/MKd7hcKA4m0',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/NIQ52qeXOBU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/ush_7RsBAGM',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/KjOTbIIov44',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/tzfdoTi8e2E',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/0Idgp07w-PA',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/8NkBqUQ-nYc',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/TkVqmu1QUSk',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/npk8586on_I',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/4Um0IDn_ax4',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/t--j8FnOUrY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/1VEVJrBF94U',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/jKvwtbrxzdY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/--LyFIjXoFY',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/Qdr4mpifNQQ',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/vAD5mhU9JUk',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/D8LcRLwZyPs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/H5yiRXDUkto',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/_0EALGr5NBs',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/2xCQuiEmBcg',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/0tkmbWNLm9E',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/2xCQuiEmBcg',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/0tkmbWNLm9E',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/yI-GZRkbJ08',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/vVyzufditLQ',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/eHXtoxL1H-E',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/c7qvP413OVU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/yi9Oytqu5hg',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/nTinYg604lE',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/4KroYsZEfio',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/174ZYtxCtr4',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/4hHLKxPtTfQ',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/cMC_s7e150o',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/pNH6_AOXTnU',
'https://unsplash.com/photos/Ul07QK2AR-0'   
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) for updating document one by one. As I understand your question that you want to update your field with a random element of the array then you can do it like as below:

```
 var pics = [
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/IGmMRSuh6Qo',
     'https://unsplash.com/photos/t4mQXex4Peo'
     ]

function random() {
    return (pics[Math.floor(Math.random()*pics.length)]);
}

db.COLLECTION_NAME.find().forEach( function(myDoc) {
    const res = random()
         db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").update({ _id: ObjectId(myDoc._id) }, {
    $set: {
        "YOUR_FIELD_NAME": res
    }
    })
} );
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you enlighten me as to why my output different yours. In your way, we need to find 5000 docs first and then update one by one. In my way, I knew collection have 5000 docs so I make 5000 For loop and update one by one directly.